# Merge my new disk (un allocated Space) without any loss data

Tags: partitioning, fdisk, merge

Kindly need guide about the steps how to merge an allocated space (disk 2) to my disk 1.

[image: Hard Disk 2 is contain allocated space]

When I check with `df -h`:

[image]

The target is, I want to increase the size of `/dev/sda2` because of it is almost full

```
fdisk -l
```

[image]

Please let me know, if you guys have done this with the briefly step will be much appreciate.

Comment: This looks like a Virtual Machine so you should be able to increase the size of disk 1 using the VM GUI or commands assuming it’s available on the host. If you want more space for your root partition that is the easiest way to go. Disk 2 is not showing in the output you have provided. Can you post the output of lsblk?

Answer (score 0):

You could not merge these two different disks. They are not partitions.

But you could resize it using your Hypervisor's tools if it supports such operations.

You could also create the new one disk of required size (70 Gb) and clone your old disk to it using GParted:

- Boot into Ubuntu's Live CD (**Try without installing** mode of your Ubuntu installation disk)
- Open GParted
- Select your disk with bigger size and chose **Device** -> **Create partition table** for it (Default msdos could be used)
- Select your old disk, right click it and **Copy**
- Select your new disk, right click it and **Paste**
- Apply operations if you see the newer disk marked as **Copy of /dev/sda1** or similar
- Right click newer disk -> **Manage Flags** -> Check **boot**.
- Shutdown your VM and change disks boot priority, making your new disk booted first.

[image]

I tried this on Virtualbox VM. But in my case it didn't want to boot from new disk. I've powered off the VM, renamed old `disk.vdi` to `disk.vdi.bk` and renamed new disk to `disk.vdi`. Then I removed second disk item from Virtualbox disk controller and OS booted from cloned in GParted disk.

Comment: Hi Gryu,

Many thanks for the briefly guide. I will try following the step that you have inform.
appreacite for your help :)

Cheers,
Tifa